# gem install error, index not found, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Problem: Cannot install any gem, any type. But I want to install riddle if that matters.

When I run `sudo gem install "gem_name"` I get the following error:

```
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

What to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Here is the answer!!!!
- slow connection

2) Solution
- move to a new connection.

-
This might not affect people in the 1st world, but I live in China and this was a huge problem as few people seem to have experienced this.

Basically the error means that the connection is to slow and gives up saying no index found. But there is not documentation or help out there on this, except for a few posts about changing gem sources, and MERB causing problems, but all that failed for me.

Answer (score 4):

Check your sources

```
gem sources
```

rebuild index for affected sources, e.g.

```
gem generate_index http://gems.rubyforge.org
```

Comment: I get this:

Gem::Indexer requires that the XML Builder library be installed:
 gem install builder

Comment: I installed builder manually, but same error. Index not found for and then blank...

Comment: try `sudo gem install -s http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/21724/builder-2.1.2.gem builder`

Comment: sorry missed that second comment.

Comment: mac osx 10.5.1 I tried with your last comment and get 

not in gzip format

Comment: what type of reinstall did you do? Archive and install, or erase and install. I would also advise checking if your disk permissions need repairing.

Comment: @Sam, I hit this too. Looks like rubygem 1.3.7 (not sure about 4) requires builder 2.1.2, but if you just gem install builder you get 3.0.0 which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and ran the following:

```
gem env
```

And saw that I had the following sources in my rubygems configuration:

- http://gems.rubyforge.org
- http://gems.rubyonrails.org
- http://gems.github.com

Based on other answers I've seen here and on the web I decided to remove the rubyonrails.org reference:

```
sudo gem sources -r http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

I was then able to install the gem I was trying to get without the RubyGems 1.2+ index error.

So I'd suggest trimming your list of sources down to just rubyforge and github and then trying to install the gem you want.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by

```
rm -rf ~/.gem
```

And then run "gem install" again

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the another gem source.  For example github:

```
sudo gem sources -r http://gems.rubyforge.org
sudo gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
```

Comment: The problem is not a source problem. 
I have both of those sources added.

The problem is with "index not found for". I don't know what that means, but this is the problem.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an old RubyGems version.
Upgrade to the latest RubyGems 1.3.x branch.

```
$ rubygems update --self
```

If it doesn't work (RubyGems 1.2.0 has a weird bug that prevents --self update) then install rubygems_update

```
$ wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60717/rubygems-update-1.3.5.gem
$ gem install rubygems-update-1.3.5.gem
$ update_rubygems
```

Use sudo if your os requires it.

Comment: No, that didn't work. Same problem. RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for: then blank.......

Comment: WHich is your gem version now?

Comment: sorry this took so long. RubyGems 1.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Could be a daft entry in /etc/hosts...