# RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/

### 1) I have reinstalled ruby and ruby gems from source

### 2) possible solutions that have not worked

a) try adding different sources to gem sources

b) updating gems, It's not out of date gems because I also installed 1.3.5 from source.

- I cannot do gem install, gem update... all that gets returned is the above error.

Comment: Could you paste the full error you're getting? http://gist.github.com

Also, try tacking -V onto it, it'll show which URLs aren't working.

Comment: samuelgilman~/sites/lessthancontainer$ sudo gem install -y rails
INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
 

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `gems' for #<Array:0x14008fc>

Comment: btw, is this the same as question #1855021?

Comment: Paste the *whole* error at http://gist.github.com please, this area is horrible for error dumps. Also, what does your gem -v say?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855021/gem-install-error-index-not-found-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I live in China. I just tried to gem install and gem update from my pc and I got the same error. So i postulate the error is something to do with the great firewall

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error with:
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://gemcutter.org
   - http://rubygems.org
   - http://gems.github.com
   - http://gems.rubyonrails.org
   - http://gems.rubyforge.org

I removed the last two from my .gemrc and it fixed the problem. It seems that it was gems.rubyonrails.org causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Remove http://gems.rubyonrails.org from gem sources

```
gem sources -r http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to delete one of your source_cache files.
If you run:

```
gem env
```

That will show you your GEM PATHS. The bad source cache is in one of those.  After that add github and gemcutter back in- just in case!

Comment: I only have http://gems.rubyforge.org/

Wow, this crazy. I reinstalled my os, ruby, ruby gems and I still get this problem

Comment: You need to add github and gemcutter back in after you delete all of the source_cache files.  You should make sure you can actually see all of those gem loading URLs from your box.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this error trying to install i18n using `gem`. It turns out that my company firewall blocks traffic with `Content-Type` of `binary/octet-stream`. Asking the network admin to temporarily let those through worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in China, make sure you have a VPN, or there will be some networking problem because of the Great Firewall.

Answer (score -1):

This is [reported as a bug here](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27575&group_id=126&atid=575)