# WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:    RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance

Tags: ruby, rubygems

WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.

If anyone can walk me through this problem I will give them $50.00

I've exhausted google, have reinstalled everything.

All i want to to is

gem install ...

that's it

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855021/gem-install-error-index-not-found-ruby-on-rails

Comment: maybe you should focus on finding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I live in China. I just tried to gem install and gem update from my pc and I got the same error. So i postulate the error is something to do with the great firewall

Comment: Or any firewall for that matter. Actually it wasn't because I was in China it was something to do with the wireless router so move to a hard connection if you can! just my advice

Answer (score 5):

remove the culprit URL.

in my case, I am on Centos 5.4 and the full error message I am getting is:

```
root# gem install rack
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
    http://rubyworks.rubyforge.org/redhat/5/GEMS/x86_64/

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
ERROR:  could not find gem rack locally or in a repository
root#
```

Solution:
edit your .gemrc
and remove the address that makes it fails.

try again and remove the next broken url if any
until it_just_works(tm);

more it, the one above was the only one.

see the content of my .gemrc config file.

```
root# cat .gemrc 
--- 
:verbose: true
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:benchmark: false
:update_sources: true
:backtrace: false
:disabledsources: 
- http://rubyworks.rubyforge.org/redhat/5/GEMS/x86_64/
:sources: 
- http://gems.rubyforge.org
- http://gems.github.com
- http://gems.rubyforge.org
- http://gems.github.com/
- http://gems.rubyonrails.org/
root# pwd
/root
root#
```

Et Voila!

you would be very kind to paypal 50$ to my email address as promised.

thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and you were right, it was just a bad source: - http://gems.rubyonrails.org

Comment: the problem was due to firewall not bad url

Comment: somekool thanks for the try, I changed the sources a few times but it was really just because of a firewall issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 7? I used windows xp, it's ok, but under windows 7 it failed!! The same error as yours.

Comment: I'm using a osx. The problem was something to do with my connection. I only get this error when I am at my house but if I go to another location such as a coffee shop I don't get this error and can gem install gem source etc... Plus, I am currently living in China but that will change because it is not a place for a programmer to live if they use western sources of information.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this problem but only from my home WiFi connection.  If I plugin to the router it goes away.  I'm sure it is something to do with my configuration but finding it is another story.

Comment: Oh, i wish i would have tried plugging directly into the router. I discovered the problem when I went to a local coffee shop to use their internet and just ended up going for a coffee each time I need to get a new gem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar situation....

```
--- 
:verbose: true
:update_sources: true
:sources: 
- http://gems.rubyforge.org/
- http://gems.github.com
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:backtrace: false
:benchmark: false
```

You can also use either of the following to see what URLs you have.

```
gem env
gem sources
```

When I tried "http://gems.github.com" it no longer works!

So I updated my gemrc this way:

```
sudo gem sources -r http://gems.github.com
```

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to had github.com to your gem sources :

gem sources -a http://gems.github.com

Should do the trick