# Any other ways to install Heroku except gem install

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, heroku, installation, rubygems

`gem install heroku` failed with following message and I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857719/warning-rubygems-1-2-index-not-found-for-rubygems-will-revert-to-legacy-in), but it failed also. Is there any other way I can install Heroku?

```
WARNING: RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.   
ERROR: could not find gem heroku locally or in a repository.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the gem to version `1.3.6` seem solve the problem.

However, `gem update --system` does not work on Ubuntu platforms, and `apt-get install rubygems1.8` always bring you to version `1.2.0`.

Here is the trick to update your gems to latest one,1.3.6, by the time of writing:

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo update_rubygems
```

And the credit goes [here](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2008/11/23/RubyGems-1-3-1-on-Ubuntu-8-10).

Finally, by all means avoid installing the gems manually, my experience taught me.

Answer (score 5):

Heroku now offers a standalone client, called the Heroku Toolbelt. Check out https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ for current installation instructions.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to bypass the problem by downloading the heroku gem from rubygems.org and install from the local copy.

1. go to http://rubygems.org/gems/heroku and click the download link to download version 1.8.5
2. then move into the download folder and do a `gem install --local heroku-1.8.5.gem` ,but follow the instruction to install the dependency first

Comment: dependencies. you're right. thanks for editing! didn't really think about that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your Rubygems version is not up to date.
Try `sudo gem update --system` and/or `sudo gem install rubygems-update; sudo update_rubygems` before trying to install the heroku gem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if you're running Debian and cannot use `gem update --system`, try installing a version of rubygems that is >1.2 from backports. I used `aptitude -t lenny-backports install rubygems` and then rubygems could actually access the online repository.

Answer (score 0):

To install Heroku in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

This installs the heroku snap package successfully, and it is the recommended way of installing Heroku CLI in Ubuntu at the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) website. When this was posted `sudo snap install --classic heroku` installs the latest version of Heroku.